# Having trouble declaring/initializing array of CGPoints

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, cgpoint

Like most of my problems recently, i think it's a syntax problem. I know what i want to do but i don't know how to write it. I am trying to create a Jigsaw-type application. The CGPoints represent the center point of where each image should be.

1. I have created 40 images and put them into an array.
2. I want to create 40 CGPoints and put all these points in an array.
3. The image at images[0] has a corresponding center at cgpoints[0] - or rather this is where the image should be placed in the jigsaw.

I'm having trouble declaring/initializing the array of CGPoints though. Below is the code:

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DSAAssignmentViewController2 : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *passedData;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblDisplayPreviousInput;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgOriginal;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img4;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img5;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img6;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img7;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img8;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img9;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img10;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img11;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img12;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img13;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img14;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img15;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img16;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img17;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img18;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img19;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img20;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img21;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img22;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img23;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img24;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img25;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img26;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img27;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img28;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img29;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img30;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img31;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img32;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img33;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img34;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img35;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img36;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img37;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img38;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img39;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img40;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *imageViews;

@property CGPoint *holder1;
@property CGPoint *holder2;
@property CGPoint *holder3;
@property CGPoint *holder4;
@property CGPoint *holder5;
@property CGPoint *holder6;
@property CGPoint *holder7;
@property CGPoint *holder8;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *holders;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "DSAAssignmentViewController2.h"

@interface DSAAssignmentViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation DSAAssignmentViewController2
@synthesize lblDisplayPreviousInput;
@synthesize imgOriginal;
@synthesize img1;
@synthesize img2;
@synthesize img3;
@synthesize img4;
@synthesize img5;
@synthesize img6;
@synthesize img7;
@synthesize img8;
@synthesize img9;
@synthesize img10;
@synthesize img11;
@synthesize img12;
@synthesize img13;
@synthesize img14;
@synthesize img15;
@synthesize img16;
@synthesize img17;
@synthesize img18;
@synthesize img19;
@synthesize img20;
@synthesize img21;
@synthesize img22;
@synthesize img23;
@synthesize img24;
@synthesize img25;
@synthesize img26;
@synthesize img27;
@synthesize img28;
@synthesize img29;
@synthesize img30;
@synthesize img31;
@synthesize img32;
@synthesize img33;
@synthesize img34;
@synthesize img35;
@synthesize img36;
@synthesize img37;
@synthesize img38;
@synthesize img39;
@synthesize img40;
@synthesize passedData;
@synthesize imageViews;

@synthesize holder1;
@synthesize holder2;
@synthesize holder3;
@synthesize holder4;
@synthesize holder5;
@synthesize holder6;
@synthesize holder7;
@synthesize holder8;
@synthesize holders;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // make jigsaw piece holders
    //create 8 points where the jigsaw pieces (images) will be placed
    CGPoint holder1 = CGPointMake(60, 644);
    CGPoint holder2 = CGPointMake(140, 644);
    CGPoint holder3 = CGPointMake(220, 644);
    CGPoint holder4 = CGPointMake(300, 644);
    CGPoint holder5 = CGPointMake(380, 644);
    CGPoint holder6 = CGPointMake(460, 644);
    CGPoint holder7 = CGPointMake(540, 644);
    CGPoint holder8 = CGPointMake(620, 644);

    // set up array of cgpoints
    holders = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: holder1],[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: holder2], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: holder3], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: holder4], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: holder5], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: holder6], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: holder7], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: holder8], nil];

    // set up array of images
    imageViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8, img9, img10, img11, img12, img13, img14, img15, img16, img17, img18, img19, img20, img21, img22, img23, img24, img25, img26, img27, img28, img29, img30, img31, img32, img33, img34, img35, img36, img37, img38, img39, img40, nil];

    NSString *welcomeMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@", passedData];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]   //show alert box with option to play or exit
                          initWithTitle: welcomeMessage 
                          message:@"Once you press \"Play\" the timer will start. Good luck!" 
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"I want out!" 
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Play",nil];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"x-coord: %f, y-coord: %f", holder1.x, holder1.y);
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
       UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    //location of current touch
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    UIView *touchedView = [touch view];
    if ([imageViews indexOfObject:touchedView] != NSNotFound) {
        // not not found means found!
        [self animateFirstTouch:touchedView withLocation:location];
    } else {
        return;
    }

}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}


-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    //location of current touch
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    UIView *touchedView = [touch view];
    [self animateReleaseTouch:touchedView withLocation:location];

}



- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setLblDisplayPreviousInput:nil];
    [self setImgOriginal:nil];
    [self setImg1:nil];
    [self setImg2:nil];
    [self setImg3:nil];
    [self setImg4:nil];
    [self setImg5:nil];
    [self setImg6:nil];
    [self setImg7:nil];
    [self setImg8:nil];
    [self setImg9:nil];
    [self setImg10:nil];
    [self setImg11:nil];
    [self setImg12:nil];
    [self setImg13:nil];
    [self setImg14:nil];
    [self setImg15:nil];
    [self setImg16:nil];
    [self setImg17:nil];
    [self setImg18:nil];
    [self setImg19:nil];
    [self setImg20:nil];
    [self setImg21:nil];
    [self setImg22:nil];
    [self setImg23:nil];
    [self setImg24:nil];
    [self setImg25:nil];
    [self setImg26:nil];
    [self setImg27:nil];
    [self setImg28:nil];
    [self setImg29:nil];
    [self setImg30:nil];
    [self setImg31:nil];
    [self setImg32:nil];
    [self setImg33:nil];
    [self setImg34:nil];
    [self setImg35:nil];
    [self setImg36:nil];
    [self setImg37:nil];
    [self setImg38:nil];
    [self setImg39:nil];
    [self setImg40:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

-(void) animateFirstTouch:(UIImageView *)image withLocation:(CGPoint)location {
    image.center = location;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.25, 1.25);  
    [UIView commitAnimations];   
}

-(void) animateReleaseTouch:(UIImageView *)image withLocation:(CGPoint)location {
    image.center = location;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);  
    [UIView commitAnimations];   
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

I can't tell if its all a bit of a mess or not. As you can see i've started with only 8 "holders", these are the CGPoints that represent the center of where the jigsaw pieces should be placed.

Comment: It's more than a bit of a mess. There is never a good reason to have 40 properties when you could just generate them programmatically and keep them in an array. That said, you should post the specific error you're getting; just saying "it doesn't work" is not helpful for people attempting to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @IanHenry Beat me to it. What's the actual problem or question here? And if you're looking for code review, that goes in the [Code Review StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry, i realise i was unclear. My problem is with the Mutable Array of CGPoints. The way I have it at the moment, i get errors stating: "Local declaration of holder1, 2, 3,..., 8 hides instance variable". This is in my .m file. I'm a novice when it comes to Obj-C and I'm not sure if i've put the right things in both the .h and .m files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

borrrden is correct. You've created a whole bunch of CGPoint pointer variables by declaring them as properties and synthesizing them. But then in your `-viewDidLoad` method you're declaring CGPoint structs--not CGPoint pointers--all with the same name as the properties you synthesized.

You don't need the `holderN` properties at all, to judge from the code. In fact, you don't even need the holderN variables in the `-viewDidLoad` method. You could easily get away with something like this:

```
- ( void )viewDidLoad
{
    holders = [ NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [ NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(60, 644) ],
                               ...,
                               [ NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(N, N) ],
                               nil ];
    ...
}
```

Hard-coding the point coordinates is poor design, though. Your best option is to put the coordinates in a plist, which you can load on demand and stuff into an array. This'll mean tweaking the coordinates is just a matter of editing the plist. No recompiling required.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the message in your comment because you declare variables with the same name as your properties in the beginning of viewDidLoad.

Comment: I'm trying to populate the `NSMutableArray *holders` with the values of `holder1,2,..., 8`. I thought this was a way to do it. I don't know how else to go about it.

Comment: You mean your intention is to set your properties?

Answer (score -2):

NSPoint is not an object so you have to either use C array: `NSPoint points[SIZE]` or use NSValue container: `[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: point]`

Comment: Hi, I've actually used `[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: point]`. The errors i'm getting are the ones mentioned in my comment above.